# How do archaic words affect on English native speakers?

Tags: word-usage, reason-why

I wonder why I need to know words like thereby, thereunto, wherewithal, hereonafter, thenceforward and others. I understand that I am unable to use them while writing an essay, because these words are abstruse. From my perspective, they can be used in legal English and in literature (books). I would like to know if they can be boring for native speakers to hear. And how do they affect upon English native speakers?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I'm afraid that the way you have framed the question makes it unanswerable; you cannot say that all native speakers will react to a particular word in a particular context at a particular time in any particular way, and whether something is "boring" or not is personal and subjective. I would submit further that I do not consider *thereby*, *thereunto*, or *wherewithal* to be archaic, though they would not be common in most casual conversations. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] and see if you can [edit] the question to clarify your interest.

Comment: *Wherewithal* is much less archaic than *thenceforward*.

Comment: *Thereby*, as an example, is quite acceptable in essays . . .

Comment: They make things more formal, but they're not all the way to boring, and many are not archaic.  There's no reason not to use them in an essay, except maybe hereonafter, which I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the comments, some of these words are quite acceptable in formal essays, although they are generally less used in casual conversations. Some of them are so archaic that you should never use them unless you're writing a legal document or a historical novel (and maybe not even then).

*Thereby* is clearly in the first category, while *thenceforward* and *hereonafter* are in the second (unless you made a typo for *hereinafter*). The others are somewhere in between.

Answer (score -1):

Most of them sound odd in daily life English. They're archaic for a reason and the reason is that people stopped using them. :)